# Redirect button directly to checkout

Tags: javascript, shopify

I want to redirect people directly to the checkout page, instead of the cart page. There are in total 5 products. All the customers buy other products, so they all need another checkout link. In the start I tried to do that in the HTML code, but of course that didn't worked.

Then I found https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/ with some helpful tips. But I can't implement it into my website.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't implement it"? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to extend the shopify help for ajax add to cart and redirect to the checkout like:

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', $("form[action='/cart/add']").serialize()).
   always(function(data){
   window.location.href ='/checkout';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Shopify does not provide the this functionality as you want.
you can not go to directly checkout page. 
you must have to go first in to the cart page.

Comment: Yes you can! You can use 'return_to' input or directly submit to the checkout using "/checkout" if you add the product first.